# InstallShield PackageForTheWeb compatibility

Tags: installation, installshield

Is the classic InstallShield PFT 4.00 wrapper still working with modern OSes, one customer reported an error and I am not sure if its related to PFT:

"program is not a valid 32 bit program."

This is system information: Microsoft Windows XP Media Center Edition Version 2002 Service Pack 3.  2.8 Ghz  1GB RAM

PFT wrapped setupper works nicely with normal XP and Vista.

PFT is called setup.exe and there is autorun:
[autorun]
open=setup.exe
icon=setup.exe,0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the classic pftw wrapper works on modern os's, although I can't be certain about windows 7 since I haven't tried. Media center can't be that different from XP that a program wouldn't run, this sounds more like someone downloading over an ftp connection set to ascii...